# Service endpoint for AWS Lex Bot

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I created Bot on AWS Lex, that internally calls LAmbda functions to fulfill different intents. I tested on the AWS Lex console, and it is working fine for both text and Speech.

I also exported to Alexa Skill Kit (part of developer.amazon.com/alexa) using link - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/export-your-amazon-lex-bot-schema-to-the-alexa-skills-kit/

Questions -

1. What would be the correct service endpoint, that I have to pass in Configurations tab (in Alexa Skill Kit). Currently I passed -   “https://runtime.lex.us-east-1.amazonaws.com” . But it is not working. Can you help me here ?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to mix up Lex with Alexa. Lex is the technology behind Alexa. You only need to integrate your Lambda function not Lex url. For that you can provide Lambda ARN under the EndPoint section of the skill builder like below,

[image]

Comment: Just to add to what Viswanathan has mentioned, the lambda function you used for lex bot might not work as it is for Alexa skill. For example, the json structure of slots varies from lex bot to Alexa skill. Make sure to change the lambda function.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will have to submit lambda Arn which looks like: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:{acc_id}:function:{function_name}

Note: Please make sure the right region is picked up